# Delete in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the value of hidden column Field on Click of Delete button in GridView. I am trying to get rowindex value first and then column value but getting an error as on below code-

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

```
int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
Id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
```

Comment: Please post your view code also

Comment: This is a well know problem explained in the duplicate posted. However your questions lacks of the required context to understand how this exception raises